# How two compare two array list items in linq query vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two querys(qry1 returning [a1],[a2]; qry2 returning [a1],[a2],[a3]). So i want to compare these two queries . If they are not equal perform some function. Below is the query i am trying.i dont want to compare with 'count' operator.

```
Dim Qry1 = (From x In db1.Approvals _
        Where x.ID = tId _
        And x.APPROVALID = GetRqstID(thisId) _
        Select x.APPROVERID).ToList()


 Dim Qry2 = (From x In db.Resources _
             Join y In db.Users On x.USER_ID Equals y.USER_ID _
             Where x.ID = tskIdIn _
             And x.TYPE = rsrcType _
             Order By y.FIRST_NAME _
            Select x.USER_ID).ToList()


 If ((Qry1.ToArray) <> (Qry2.ToArray)) Then
---
---
 End If
```

Comment: Try looking up UNION JOIN INTERSECT. You've added a c# tag to a vb.net question -- you may want to remove that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Qry1.Count() != Qry2.Count() || 
    Qry1.Except(Qry2).Count() > 0 ||
    Qry2.Except(Qry1).Count() > 0)  
 // not the same.
```

I do the count check first because of short circuit it will speed up most cases.  It is not needed if you are doing the other two.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I dont want to use count i want to compare the values and check if they are equal or not

Comment: @Adu - please read what Except does.  You don't understand my answer it does what you want.  That is why I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Linq Intersect will be best candidate.

```
int[] id1 = { 44, 26, 92, 30, 71, 38 };
int[] id2 = { 39, 59, 83, 47, 26, 4, 30 };

IEnumerable<int> both = id1.Intersect(id2);

foreach (int id in both)
    Console.WriteLine(id);

/*
 This code produces the following output and means you have some element repeating on both array instance. If there is no matching element then you can perform the operation that you wanted.:

 26
 30
*/
```

Comment: Actually i want to check if both the queries are equal are not in sense not the count the values example :q1(a1,a2);q2(a2,a3) even the count is same the values are different

Comment: We are not talking in terms of count rather availability of elements.